# Is there a way of accessing Teams Reports & Analytics data via MS Graph API same as in Teams Admin Center

Tags: microsoft-teams

This way we can make our dashboards for each school, each class and subject.

It will be useful in monitoring active/inactive schools, classes, teachers and students.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the reports that you can see in the Teams Admin center are available via the [user activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/resources/microsoft-teams-user-activity-reports?view=graph-rest-1.0&WT.mc_id=m365-00000-wmastyka) and [device usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/resources/microsoft-teams-device-usage-reports?view=graph-rest-1.0&WT.mc_id=m365-00000-wmastyka) Graph APIs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes, I have started using "reportRoot: getTeamsUserActivityUserDetail" report, but it still doesn't give me the desired results. Ww work for schools, so I want class-wise and subject-wise analytics.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getteamsuseractivityuserdetail?view=graph-rest-1.0 This link partially serves our purpose, but I need to maintain this detail data for each user, then match with my class members, and then show this data in some dashboard, similar to that of the dashboards in Teams Admin Center.

Answer (score 1):

Hi @Ravi Could you please have a look on this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/education-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) and it would be very help full to you.